# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to display users with respective role

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am implementing ASP.NET Identity in ASP.NET Core-6 Web API

Entities:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have this DTOs:

```
public class AllRoleListDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class AllUserListDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Fullname
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
}
```

I did the Mapping using AutoMapper as shown below:

```
public class AdminMapperProfile: Profile
{
    public AdminMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ApplicationUser, AllUserListDto>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<ApplicationRole, AllRoleListDto>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

I want to display all the users with there respective roles using:

```
public async Task<PagedResponse<AllUserListDto>> GetAllUserAsync(int page, int limit)
{
    var response = new PagedResponse<AllUserListDto>();

    try
    {
        if (page >= 1 && limit >= 1)
        {


            var userQueryable = _context.ApplicationUsers.AsQueryable();
            var pagedUsers = await userQueryable.ToPagedListAsync(page, limit);

            response.Result = _mapper.Map<List<AllUserListDto>>(pagedUsers.ToList());
            response.TotalPages = pagedUsers.PageCount;
            response.Page = pagedUsers.PageNumber;
            response.PerPage = pagedUsers.PageSize;

        }
        else
        {
            response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto()
            {
                ErrorCode = 400,
                Message = "The page number and page size must be greater than 1!"
            };
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.Error = new ErrorResponseDto()
        {
            ErrorCode = 500,
            Message = ex.Message
        };
    }

    return response;
}
```

What I have above only get all the users without the roles.

How do I get all the users with their respective roles as shown below?

```
UserName  |  FirstName  |  LastName  |  Role
```

Thanks

Comment: `_context.ApplicationUsers.Include(u => u.Roles).ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)` to get the respective roles, here is a simple demo( I have used MVC here to demonstrate it more clearly):

First, Create a viewModel

```
public class UserRole
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public List<string> roles { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    }
```

Then in controller:

```
public class RegisterController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

        public RegisterController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _roleManager = roleManager;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> show()
        {
            List<UserRole> userRoles = new List<UserRole>();

            //get all users
            var user = _userManager.Users.ToList();

            foreach (var item in user)
            {
                UserRole userRole = new UserRole();
                userRole.UserName = item.UserName;
                userRole.FirstName = item.FirstName;
                userRole.LastName = item.LastName;
                userRole.Email = item.Email;

                //get the user's roles
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(item);
                foreach (var roleName in roles)
                {
                    userRole.roles.Add(roleName);
                }

                userRoles.Add(userRole);
            }

            return View(userRoles);
        }
}
```

View:

```
@model List<UserRole>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <h2>@item.UserName</h2>
    <h2>@item.FirstName</h2>
    <h2>@item.LastName</h2>
    <h2>@item.Email</h2>
    
    @foreach (var role in item.roles)
    {
        <h3>@role</h3>
    }

    <h1>==================================</h1>

}
```

Demo:
[image]